# Euler's method and Riemann sum

Tags: integration

For: $F(0) = 0$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$

Euler's method: $F(0+h) = F(0)+ hF'(0) = 0 + hf(0)$

Continuing the process, $F(10h) = hf(0)+hf(h)+hf(2h)+.....hf(9h)$

This resembles the Riemann sum: $\Sigma_{i=1}^n f(x_i)(x_i - x_{i-1})$

Therefore my professor used Euler's method to solve integral problems.

Example: $\int_3^{3.09} f(x) dx = 0.81.$ Approximate $f(3).$
$F(x) = hf(x)$

$0.81=0.09 f(x)$

$f(x) = 3$

My question: 
How did $F(x+h) = F(x) + hf(x)$ become $F(x) = hf(x)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion is mostly from slightly sloppy notation. You have

$$F(x+h)-F(x) \approx h f(x)$$

so

$$F(3.09)-F(3) \approx 0.09 f(3)$$

and

$$F(3.09)-F(3) = \int_3^{3.09} f(x) dx$$